# sagepay form integration - Not able to decrypt the $_GET['crypt'] string returned

Tags: zen-cart, opayo

I have placed a test transaction using following encryption -

```
<?php
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
$pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
$key = "use your SagePAY encryption key here";
$iv = $key;

$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
{
    $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

    $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
}
return $enc;
}
$str = "Currency=GBP";
$datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
$cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);
?>
<html>
<form name="pp_form" action="SagePay test url" method="post">
<input name="VPSProtocol" type="hidden" value=3.00 />
<input name="TxType" type="hidden" value=PAYMENT />
<input name="Vendor" type="hidden" value="YOUR SAGEPAY ACCOUNT NAME HERE"     />
<input name="Crypt" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $cryptpadded;?> />
<p>Click here to submit 
    <input type="submit" value="here">
</p>
</form>
</html>
```

But when the SagePay returns encrypted string, I am not sure how to decrypt this encrypted data as we will have to do decrypt it while creating order at our end. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the integration docs? There is also a PHP integration kit for the FORM integration.

Comment: This is covered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525026/sage-pay-v3-00-integration