# Sage Pay v3.00 Integration

Tags: integration, protocols, opayo, cs-cart

Can anyone help me incorporate the Sagepay v3.00 AES/CBC/PKCS#5 algorithm (encryption) into the following file. I'm really struggling to understand how to include so that customer data is encrypted to the new standard and then decrypted on the way back. Using Sagepay Form with a very old version of cs-cart, though have successfully managed to upgrade from version 2.22 to 2.23, but Sagepay are pulling all support from July.

Not sure how much of this script is relevant to the encryption:

```
<?php

if ( !defined('IN_CSCART') ) { die('Access denied'); }

if (defined('PAYMENT_NOTIFICATION')) {  

// Get the password
$payment_id=db_get_field("SELECT $db_tables[payments].payment_id FROM $db_tables[payments] LEFT JOIN $db_tables[payment_processors] ON $db_tables[payment_processors].processor_id = $db_tables[payments].processor_id WHERE $db_tables[payment_processors].processor_script='protx_form.php'");
$processor_data = fn_get_payment_method_data($payment_id);

$result = "&".simpleXor(base64Decode($_REQUEST['crypt']), $processor_data["params"]["password"])."&";

preg_match("/Status=(.+)&/U", $result, $a);
if(trim($a[1]) == "OK") {
    $pp_response['order_status'] = ($processor_data["params"]["transaction_type"] == 'PAYMENT') ? 'P' : 'O';
    preg_match("/TxAuthNo=(.+)&/U", $result, $authno);
    $pp_response["reason_text"] = "AuthNo: ".$authno[1];
    preg_match("/VPSTxID={(.+)}/U", $result, $transaction_id);
    $pp_response["transaction_id"] = @$transaction_id[1];
} else {
    $pp_response['order_status'] = 'F';
    preg_match("/StatusDetail=(.+)&/U", $result, $stat);
    $pp_response["reason_text"] = "Status: ".trim($stat[1])." (".trim($a[1]).") ";
}
preg_match("/AVSCV2=(.*)&/U", $result, $avs);
if(!empty($avs[1])) {
    $pp_response['descr_avs'] = $avs[1];
}
include $payment_files_dir.'payment_cc_complete.php';
fn_order_placement_routines($order_id);

}
else
{
    global $http_location, $b_order, $_total_back;

    $post_address = ($processor_data['params']['testmode'] != "N") ? "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" : "https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp";

    $post["VPSProtocol"] = "2.23";
    $post["TxType"] = $processor_data["params"]["transaction_type"];
    $post["Vendor"] = htmlspecialchars($processor_data["params"]["vendor"]);

    // Form Cart products
    $strings = 0;
    if (is_array($cart['products'])) {
        $strings += count($cart['products']);
    }

    if (!empty($cart['products'])) {
        foreach ($cart['products'] as $v) {
            $_product = db_get_field("SELECT product FROM $db_tables[product_descriptions] WHERE product_id='$v[product_id]' AND lang_code='$cart_language'");
            $products_string .= ":".str_replace(":", " ", $_product).":".$v['amount'].":".fn_format_price($v['subtotal']/$v['amount']).":::".fn_format_price($v['subtotal']);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($cart['payment_surcharge'])) {
        $products_string .= ":Payment surcharge:---:---:---:---:".fn_format_price($cart['payment_surcharge']);
        $strings ++;
    }
    if (!empty($cart['shipping_cost'])) {
        $products_string .= ":Shipping cost:---:---:---:---:".fn_format_price($cart['shipping_cost']);
        $strings ++;
    }
    $post_encrypted .= "Basket=".$strings.$products_string;

    $post["Crypt"] = base64_encode(simpleXor($post_encrypted, $processor_data["params"]["password"]));
    $post["Crypt"] = htmlspecialchars($post["Crypt"]);

    $msg = fn_get_lang_var('text_cc_processor_connection');
    $msg = str_replace('[processor]', 'Protx Server', $msg);

echo <<<EOT
<html>
<body onLoad="document.process.submit();">
<form action="{$post_address}" method="POST" name="process">
<INPUT type=hidden name="VPSProtocol" value="{$post['VPSProtocol']}">
<INPUT type=hidden name="Vendor" value="{$post['Vendor']}">
<INPUT type=hidden name="TxType" value="{$post['TxType']}">
<INPUT type=hidden name="Crypt" value="{$post['Crypt']}">
<p>
<div align=center>{$msg}</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
}

exit;

//
// ---------------- Additional functions ------------
//
function simpleXor($InString, $Key) {
$KeyList = array();
$output = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($Key); $i++){
    $KeyList[$i] = ord(substr($Key, $i, 1));
}
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($InString); $i++) {
    $output.= chr(ord(substr($InString, $i, 1)) ^ ($KeyList[$i % strlen($Key)]));
}

return $output;
}

function base64Decode($scrambled) {
// Initialise output variable
$output = "";
// Fix plus to space conversion issue
$scrambled = str_replace(" ","+",$scrambled);
// Do encoding
$output = base64_decode($scrambled);
// Return the result
return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try dropping the following functions into the script, then swapping out simpleXor for  encryptAes. Make sure that you also add an '@' symbol as the first character of the crypt string (and strip it off when decoding the response from Sage Pay).

```
function addPKCS5Padding($input)
{
     $blockSize = 16;
     $padd = "";
     $length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
{
     $padd .= chr($length);
}
     return $input . $padd;
}

function removePKCS5Padding($input)
{
    $blockSize = 16;
    $padChar = ord($input[strlen($input) - 1]);
    $unpadded = substr($input, 0, (-1) * $padChar);
    return $unpadded;
}


function encryptAes($string, $key)
{
    $string = addPKCS5Padding($string);
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
    return  strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}


function decryptAes($strIn, $password)
{
    $strInitVector = $password;
    $strIn = pack('H*', $hex);
    $string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $password, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$strInitVector);
    return removePKCS5Padding($string);
}
```

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to incorporate your script into mine exactly as you think it should be so I can test. I really have no idea what parts of my script I would need to remove and where to add yours, plus where to place the '@' symbol etc

Comment: If you want to contact me directly (details via profile / linked in) it might be easier - I don't want to share vendor account details publicly!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I can't test it, so let me know how you get on.

```
<?php

    if ( !defined('IN_CSCART') ) { die('Access denied'); }

    if (defined('PAYMENT_NOTIFICATION')) {  

    // Get the password
    $payment_id=db_get_field("SELECT $db_tables[payments].payment_id FROM $db_tables[payments] LEFT JOIN $db_tables[payment_processors] ON $db_tables

    [payment_processors].processor_id = $db_tables[payments].processor_id WHERE $db_tables[payment_processors].processor_script='protx_form.php'");
    $processor_data = fn_get_payment_method_data($payment_id);


    #Rik added:
    $result = "&".decryptAes($_REQUEST['crypt'], $processor_data["params"]["password"])."&";

    #$result = "&".simpleXor(base64Decode($_REQUEST['crypt']), $processor_data["params"]["password"])."&";

    preg_match("/Status=(.+)&/U", $result, $a);
    if(trim($a[1]) == "OK") {
        $pp_response['order_status'] = ($processor_data["params"]["transaction_type"] == 'PAYMENT') ? 'P' : 'O';
        preg_match("/TxAuthNo=(.+)&/U", $result, $authno);
        $pp_response["reason_text"] = "AuthNo: ".$authno[1];
        preg_match("/VPSTxID={(.+)}/U", $result, $transaction_id);
        $pp_response["transaction_id"] = @$transaction_id[1];
    } else {
        $pp_response['order_status'] = 'F';
        preg_match("/StatusDetail=(.+)&/U", $result, $stat);
        $pp_response["reason_text"] = "Status: ".trim($stat[1])." (".trim($a[1]).") ";
    }
    preg_match("/AVSCV2=(.*)&/U", $result, $avs);
    if(!empty($avs[1])) {
        $pp_response['descr_avs'] = $avs[1];
    }
    include $payment_files_dir.'payment_cc_complete.php';
    fn_order_placement_routines($order_id);

    }
    else
    {
        global $http_location, $b_order, $_total_back;

        $post_address = ($processor_data['params']['testmode'] != "N") ? "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp" : 

    "https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp";

        $post["VPSProtocol"] = "2.23";
        $post["TxType"] = $processor_data["params"]["transaction_type"];
        $post["Vendor"] = htmlspecialchars($processor_data["params"]["vendor"]);

        // Form Cart products
        $strings = 0;
        if (is_array($cart['products'])) {
            $strings += count($cart['products']);
        }

        if (!empty($cart['products'])) {
            foreach ($cart['products'] as $v) {
                $_product = db_get_field("SELECT product FROM $db_tables[product_descriptions] WHERE product_id='$v[product_id]' AND lang_code='$cart_language'");
                $products_string .= ":".str_replace(":", " ", $_product).":".$v['amount'].":".fn_format_price($v['subtotal']/$v['amount']).":::".fn_format_price($v

    ['subtotal']);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($cart['payment_surcharge'])) {
            $products_string .= ":Payment surcharge:---:---:---:---:".fn_format_price($cart['payment_surcharge']);
            $strings ++;
        }
        if (!empty($cart['shipping_cost'])) {
            $products_string .= ":Shipping cost:---:---:---:---:".fn_format_price($cart['shipping_cost']);
            $strings ++;
        }
        $post_encrypted .= "Basket=".$strings.$products_string;


    #Rik added:

     $post["Crypt"] = "@".encryptAes($post_encrypted, $processor_data["params"]["password"]);

    #    $post["Crypt"] = base64_encode(simpleXor($post_encrypted, $processor_data["params"]["password"]));
    #    $post["Crypt"] = htmlspecialchars($post["Crypt"]);

        $msg = fn_get_lang_var('text_cc_processor_connection');
        $msg = str_replace('[processor]', 'Protx Server', $msg);

    echo <<<EOT
    <html>
    <body onLoad="document.process.submit();">
    <form action="{$post_address}" method="POST" name="process">
    <INPUT type=hidden name="VPSProtocol" value="{$post['VPSProtocol']}">
    <INPUT type=hidden name="Vendor" value="{$post['Vendor']}">
    <INPUT type=hidden name="TxType" value="{$post['TxType']}">
    <INPUT type=hidden name="Crypt" value="{$post['Crypt']}">
    <p>
    <div align=center>{$msg}</div>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    EOT;
    }

    exit;

    //
    // ---------------- Additional functions ------------
    //
    function simpleXor($InString, $Key) {
    $KeyList = array();
    $output = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($Key); $i++){
        $KeyList[$i] = ord(substr($Key, $i, 1));
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($InString); $i++) {
        $output.= chr(ord(substr($InString, $i, 1)) ^ ($KeyList[$i % strlen($Key)]));
    }

    return $output;
    }

    function base64Decode($scrambled) {
    // Initialise output variable
    $output = "";
    // Fix plus to space conversion issue
    $scrambled = str_replace(" ","+",$scrambled);
    // Do encoding
    $output = base64_decode($scrambled);
    // Return the result
    return $output;
    }


    #added by Rik

    function addPKCS5Padding($input)
    {
         $blockSize = 16;
         $padd = "";
         $length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
    {
         $padd .= chr($length);
    }
         return $input . $padd;
    }

    function removePKCS5Padding($input)
    {
        $blockSize = 16;
        $padChar = ord($input[strlen($input) - 1]);
        $unpadded = substr($input, 0, (-1) * $padChar);
        return $unpadded;
    }


    function encryptAes($string, $key)
    {
        $string = addPKCS5Padding($string);
        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
        return  strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
    }


    function decryptAes($strIn, $password)
    {

    #Sagepay specific - remove the '@'
    $strIn = substr($strIn,1)

        $strInitVector = $password;
        $strIn = pack('H*', $hex);
        $string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $password, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$strInitVector);
        return removePKCS5Padding($string);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I've tried it (after changing $post["VPSProtocol"] = "3.00";) but it just hangs on the 'connecting to Sage Pay'. No error log though which doesn't help. I sense you are very close to sussing this out if you can possibly take another swing at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*First build your data. */

$data = 'variableA='.$this->variableA;
$data .= '&variableB='.$this->variableB;
...
$data .= '&variableZ='.$this->variableZ;

/** Encript data */
$dataEncrip = $this->encData($data);


/** function to Encrypt *//
public function encData($data){
  $data = $this->pkcs5_pad( $data, 16);
  $dataEnc = "@".bin2hex( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                          $this->passwordToEncript,
                                          $data,
                                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                          $this->getPasswordToEncrypt()));
  return $dataEnc;                                                           
}

 /** Pkcs5_pad */
public function pkcs5_pad( $data, $blocksize ){
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen( $data ) % $blocksize);
    return $data . str_repeat( chr( $pad ), $pad );
}
```