# Sage Form Integration

Tags: forms, integration, opayo

I have been trying to integrate Sage Pay using their form integration but cannot get passed the infamous 5080 error. I have been through 10 days of back and forth with Sage support and thay have conceded that they can no longer help and are convinced it is an encryption issue. I have also trawled through the answers here and I cannot seem to get the solution. I have done many integrations using other systems before but the lack of feedback from the system is very frustrating makes debugging almost impossible

Things I can confirm:
- PHP Version 7.0.15, as part of Wordpress install
- passing unique VendorTxCode
- passing all required fields with live success & failure URLS
- passing VPSProtocal, TxType, VendorName and Crypt (confirmed by viewing network tool in Chrome aftre request fails)
- tried both test and live portal using the relevant keys and correct gateways
- had numerous showposts viewed by support and verified as correct format
- confirmed the encryption - supplied an unencrypted string to support, their escalation team encrypted the string and sent back encrypted string - used a string compare app to compare strings and they are identical
- I cannot seem to see Invalid transactions in portal as I dont have a transations tab to view and support said thay cannot even see the request attempst hitting the server.

They keep telling me its an encryption issue Any suggestions as how to best debug this or any unapparent solutions that helped others woudl be of great help - im not sure what is best to post here for you to see but I can as required

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log into My Sage Pay with your admin credentials, create a user and give that user permission to see transactions (etc - just click the lot!). Log in as that user and you will be able to see transactions. Look under Invalid, and you should see the reason.
2. Check you are using the correct encryption password. They are different for live / test
3. Failing that, post your unencrypted crypt string here - I will look at it and tell you where you are going wrong.

https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp?VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=sagepaylabs2&Crypt=@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

Comment: thanks for this Rik .. Step 1 complete (first time I got his advice) I can see the test transactions that support processed to ensure account was working ... I cannot however see any failed transactions. I mentioned this to support - it seems to be failing far to quickly to be processing anything. Can confirm I am using live gateway and correct password.

Comment: String as requested : VendorTxCode=tba_58907200d89c4&Amount=50.00&Currency=EUR&Description=BabysittingFees&BillingSurname=Sname&BillingFirstnames=Fname&BillingAddress1=BAddress1&BillingCity=BCity&BillingPostCode=00000&BillingCountry=IE&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname&DeliverySurname=Sname&DeliveryAddress1=DAddrss1&DeliveryCity=DCity&DeliveryPostCode=00000&DeliveryCountry=IE&SuccessURL=https://example.com/success&FailureURL=https://example.com/failure

Comment: When I tried this, I got errors - turns out saving the string as Unicode reveals loads of whitespace in the string which was causing issues in the encryption. Save the string as Unicode and clear out any whitespace and try again. Oh, and you need to add the protocol onto the successURL.

Comment: Cheers Rik - the protocol is there - seemed to disappear when I pasted in to the comment box here - i'm a little confused as to where the white space is coming from - can I just bounce the encryption process off you 1)create the string ...  2) apply PKCS5 Padding ...  3)encrypt using mcrypt_encrypt (using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC and password as key and initialization) ....  4) convert to hex using bin2hex  ... 5) covert to uppercase using strtoupper .... 6) prepend @ to string ...... at what point is the white space stripped out?

Comment: Not sure! Try using the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525026/sage-pay-v3-00-integration

Comment: On another note Rik - I had compared my output on a test string to that encoded by the Sagepay support and it proved to be identical ...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Rik - been through that answer and the encryotion process is identical to the one I have implemented (and descibed above) - im at a dead end - dont know what to try next - the lack of feedback from the system is just like flying blind

Comment: I encrypted your string and got errors recorded. It was full of crap like this:     amount=50.00 currency=EUR&Desâ??â??cription=Babysittingâ??â??Fees - hence I copied the string into a text file, saved as Unicode, then copied it into Eclispe, cleaned out all the white space, re-encrypted it and then it was fine....

Comment: sorry now for harping on Rik but do you think the copying / pasting in to comments here could have introduced that stuff - im just looking above and there a line break after `Des` where you were seeing the crap just trying to rule out this source of error. I think they are HTML entities added by SO. You can see these if you inspect the element in Chrome - I dont see these on my webpage when I do same - when you stripped all that out and got it to submit - any chance you could post the encoded string so I can compare to mine - i see this as the only way to verify the encryption

Comment: The encoded string will be different - I have a different encryption password

Comment: I've posted my link as an amendment to my answer (it's too long for comments!). Suffice to say, all I have changed is added https:// to  the successURL and changed the currency to GBP as EUR is not on this account. I also retyped (manually) all the field names, to get rid of that mystery crap that was appearing.

Comment: Rik, im sorry for wasting your time but I wouldn't have been able solve this with out your last post.  On Page 10 and page 11 of the official documentation it quotes the four form variables as being VPSProtocol, TxType, VendorName and Crypt - see on your post you have Vendor - not VendorName - the minute I changed that it works fine. It corrects itself by the time you get to the Appendix but of course I never copped it .... Well that is a month ill never get back - thanks for the help!! Might help someone else